# Spark replace column substring with regular expression

Tags: regex, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table in Scala Spark with the following:

```
val df = Seq(("1ST ST","NICK"),("2ND STREET","SAM"),("3RD AVE","ERIC"),("4TH AVENUE","SARAH")).toDF("STREET_NAME","NAME")
```

I want to replace the substrings `STREET` with `ST` and `AVENUE` with `AVE` in column `STREET_NAME`. I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
df.withColumn(STREET_NAME,
  regexp_replace(
    $"STREET_NAME",
    lit("STREET"),
    "ST"
  )
)
```

Or is there a better way to replace the substrings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with **`replace`** (or) **`regexp_replace()`** spark in built function.

```
df.show()
//+-----------+-----+
//|STREET_NAME| NAME|
//+-----------+-----+
//|     1ST ST| NICK|
//| 2ND STREET|  SAM|
//|    3RD AVE| ERIC|
//| 4TH AVENUE|SARAH|
//+-----------+-----+

df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")

spark.sql("select replace(replace(STREET_NAME,'STREET','ST'),'AVENUE','AVE') as STREET_NAME,NAME from tmp").show()
//+-----------+-----+
//|STREET_NAME| NAME|
//+-----------+-----+
//|     1ST ST| NICK|
//|     2ND ST|  SAM|
//|    3RD AVE| ERIC|
//|    4TH AVE|SARAH|
//+-----------+-----+

//or using regexp_replace function
df.withColumn("STREET_NAME",regexp_replace(regexp_replace(col("STREET_NAME"),"STREET","ST"),"AVENUE","AVE")).show()
//+-----------+-----+
//|STREET_NAME| NAME|
//+-----------+-----+
//|     1ST ST| NICK|
//|     2ND ST|  SAM|
//|    3RD AVE| ERIC|
//|    4TH AVE|SARAH|
//+-----------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

`lit` was not needed because the second argument should be a string pattern to match, not a column.

```
df.withColumn("STREET_NAME", regexp_replace($"STREET_NAME", "STREET", "ST"))
```